# I want to be able to change the color of the turtle when I hit a key and line when I drag the turtle but struggling to have the code interact properly

Tags: python

I am new to python and especially new the the import turtle mechanic
need help this is for an assignment I have coming up

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

paintbrush = Turtle()
screen = window()

#the code bellow is changing the color of the turtle

def green():
    paintbrush.color("green")

def red():
    paintbrush.color("red")

def blue():
    paintbrush.color("blue")

def mystery():
    r = random.random()
    g = random.random()
    b = random.random()
    paintbrush.color(r, g, b)

#this code is affecting the direction of the turtle

def dragging(x, y):
    yertle.ondrag(None)
    yertle.setheading(yertle.towards(x, y))
    yertle.goto(x, y)
    yertle.ondrag(dragging)

def main():
    paintbrush.hideturtle()
    paintbrush.width(3)
    mystery()
    window.onkey(green, "g")
    window.onkey(red, "r")
    window.onkey(blue, "b")
    window.onkey(mystery, "m")
    window.listen()
    window.onclick(paintbrush.goto)


    screen = Screen()

    yertle = Turtle('turtle')
    yertle.speed('fastest')

    yertle.ondrag(dragging)

    screen.mainloop()

main()
```

need to have def dragging interact with the rest of the code and screen

Comment: first format code to display it correctly - see buttons when you edit question (and shortcut `Ctrl+K`)

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title.

Comment: do you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it gives error on `screen = window()` because it should be `window = Screen()`

Comment: you have two turtles - `paintbrush` and `yertle` - key changes color of turtle `paintbrush` but you can't see it because you have `paintbrush.hideturtle()`. If you want to change color of visible turtle then you should change color of `yertle` (and this may need `global yertle` inside `main()` to access this turle in other functions)

Comment: you have `window.onclick(paintbrush.goto)` and `yertle.ondrag(dragging)` - and both use the same mouse button to run function, and this makes problem because both want to run code when you press button. You may have to use different button for one of function or you have to remove one of them.